# Linear least squares with spans instead of points

Tags: least-squares

I'm familiar with using linear least squares to find the best fit line of a set of points. I have a slightly different situation where I have spans as well as points.

Example:

[image]

I'm trying to find the linear best fit where the line crosses through spans as much as possible. Maybe I'm not using the right terms but searching turned up nothing. Can someone point me in a direction of how I could solve this?

(I hope this question is clear enough)

Comment: Im not quite sure i get your question, but have you tried using the average coordinates of the span (center) and fit the line based on the points and the "average points" of the spans?